# didn't set LogLevel for LoggerProvider

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

I am using a custom LoggerProvider for writing log to file. My provider is working well, but I cannot set loglevel less than "information".

I am using `loggerFactory.AddConsole(minLevel:LogLevel.Debug);` for setting the loglevel, but this is not working. I can see all events--"warning", "information", etc., but not "debug" and "trace". MinLevel in my ILogger is "information."

How do I change the level in LoggerProvider?

My ILogger:

```
public class FileLogger : ILogger
        {
            private string filePath;
            private object _lock = new object();

            private readonly Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;

            public FileLogger(string path)
            {
                filePath = path;
            }
            public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
            {
                if (formatter != null)
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        switch (logLevel)
                        {
                            case LogLevel.Debug:
                                {
                                    File.AppendAllText(filePath + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "_DEBUG.log", DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + "   " + formatter(state, exception) + Environment.NewLine);
                                    break;
                                }
                            case LogLevel.Critical:
                                {
                                    File.AppendAllText(filePath + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "_CRITICAL.log", DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + "   " + formatter(state, exception) + Environment.NewLine);
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    File.AppendAllText(filePath + System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".log", DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + "   " + formatter(state, exception) + Environment.NewLine);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My ILoggerProvider:

```
 public class FileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
        {
            private string path;

            public FileLoggerProvider(string _path)
            {
                path = _path;
            }

            public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
            {
                return new FileLogger(path);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }
```

and LoggerExtensions:

```
public static class FileLoggerExtensions
    {
        public static ILoggerFactory AddFile(this ILoggerFactory factory,
                                        string filePath)
        {
            factory.AddProvider(new Values.FileLoggerProvider(filePath));
            return factory;
        }
    }
```

My code in configure.cs

```
    loggerFactory.AddFile("C:/log/");
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(minLevel:LogLevel.Debug);
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(minLevel: LogLevel.Debug);
    var _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("FileLogger");
```